# Secured website on Tomcat 7 404

Tags: tomcat7

I have configured an application on Tomcat 7 with BASIC authentication.
In development an Test works fine, but in Production environment I dont´t recive anything. In chrome console I can see a 404 not found error.

[image]

But If I execute a curl command I can reach the page.

```
 curl -vv -u username:password http://10.XXX.XXX.21/historia/es/index.jsp
```

Could anyone helps me?

PS: If I edited Request Header, adding authentication (in Firefox) I recived a 200 status but page appears in white. I don't understand anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ... and that `curl` is from the same host as Chrome request? Sorry for stupid question, but that can make big difference.

Comment: not, curl is from another machine in the same network. I can't use chrome in this server. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think in production you try to connect to service from external network. Try add address "0.0.0.0" to listen to all addresses.
In server.xml try edit like bellow.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
           maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" 
           connectionTimeout="20000" 
           redirectPort="8443"
           address="0.0.0.0" />
```

Shutdown and startup the tomcat after that

Comment: Another issue might be the lack of the port in your URL. Usually the tomcat run on port 8080 and must be add on. Try making the GET request on http://10.XXX.XXX.21:8080/historia/es/index.jsp . And I guess the 10.XXX.XXX.21 is your external IP, if not you should use a port forwarding on port 8080.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Radulescu, I tried your configuration but it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

10.XXX.XXX.21 is private address you can call it from inside the network. You can forward connections to that host, but that is different story. Why you got 404 instead of host-not-found? Well, in that other network, the one with chrome - you can have same ip used.

Comment: When I disable security in my web.xml the page works fine.I always call inside of the network (ip or hostname to avoid issues with balancers, DNS, etc.) I think some configuration may trunk my header response. I tried with other application and it fails to.

Comment: So I don't understand this case. However you can turn on log for auth:
org.apache.catalina.realm.level = FINEST
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.level = FINEST

in your $CATALINA_BASE/conf/logging.properties.